# What is the result of a natural number power the cardinality of an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the result of  a natural number power the cardinality of an infinite set? Is it the cardinality of the infinite set?

Thank you!

Comment: That's simply $\infty$. As far as I understand, you're mixing between *Cardinal Arithmetic* and *Natural Arithmetic*. Here is a good [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1387480/131263) which explain this.

Comment: If you are referring to things like $2^{\aleph_0}$, depending on the status of the continuum hypothesis, it would be $\aleph_1$.  I.e. $2^{|\Bbb N|}=|\Bbb R|$ (*note that $|\Bbb R|\neq |\Bbb N|$.  They are both infinite, but different sizes of infinite*).  [See this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number).

Comment: Yes it is about that. What is for example $3^\aleph_0$?

Comment: @user12342494: $3^{\aleph_0}$ is the number of different functions from $\mathbb N$ to a fixed $3$-element set. This happens to be _equal to_ $2^{\aleph_0}$ or indeed to $n^{\aleph_0}$ for any finite $n$.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JMoravitz's comment is potentially misleading. $2^{\aleph_0}$ always equals $|\mathbb R|$; whether this cardinality is _also_ $\aleph_1$ is what the Continuum Hypothesis is about.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Your comment is also misleading in the sense that $e^5$ is a perfectly valid answer to the question "what is the number $x$ for which $\ln x=5$?"; in the same manner, $\aleph_2^{2^{\aleph_{42}}}$ is a perfectly valid answer to a question about cardinal arithmetic, even if we can't quite say for which $\alpha$ it is equal to $\aleph_\alpha$.  Not to mention that we have the $\beth$ numbers to help and compensate for this a little bit (although not enough, admittedly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming by "natural number power the cardinalty of an infinite set you mean $n^{|X|}$)

Recall that given two cardinals $\kappa,\lambda$, the cardinal $\lambda^\kappa$ is the cardinality of the set of all functions $\kappa \to \lambda$.

Let $X$ be an infinite set with cardinality $\kappa$. The value of $n^\kappa$ for a natural number $n$ depends on $n$, coming down to three cases:

- $n=0$, in which case $0^\kappa=0$ as there is no function from a non-empty set to $0=\emptyset$.
- $n=1$, in which case $1^\kappa=1$ as there is exactly one function from a non-empty set to $1=\{\emptyset\}$.
- $n>1$, in which case $n^\kappa=2^\kappa$ is strictly larger than $\kappa$. The equality $n^\kappa=2^\kappa$ for $n\geq 2$ is because $2\leq n \leq 2^\kappa$ and monotonicity 
  $$2^\kappa \leq n^\kappa \leq (2^\kappa)^\kappa =2^{\kappa^2}=2^\kappa$$
  along with the result that $\kappa^2=\kappa$ for $\kappa$ infinite by AC.

If, on the other hand, you mean $\kappa^n$, then using the Axiom of Choice it can be shown that $\kappa^2=\kappa$, as above, and so by induction $\kappa^n=\kappa$ for all $n\geq 1$.  Naturally, $\kappa^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is answered by the following theorem:

**Theorem**. For cardinal numbers $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ such that $1 < \mathfrak{a} \leq b$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ is *transfinite*, we have:

$\mathfrak{a}^{\mathfrak{b}} = 2^{\mathfrak{b}}$

The proof of the theorem is a fairly easy consequence of the following two lemmas.

**Lemma 1**. If $\mathfrak{a}$ is a cardinal such that $\mathfrak{a}^2 = \mathfrak{a}$, then $\mathfrak{a} = 2 \mathfrak{a} = 3 \mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}^2$.

**Lemma 2**. If $\mathfrak{a}$ is a *transfinite* cardinal, then $\mathfrak{a}^2 = \mathfrak{a}$.

The proof of Lemma 2, in turn, depends essentially on the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Your lemma easily implies the claim for _finite_ $\mathfrak a$, but it seems to be not entirely trivial to extend it to infinite $\mathfrak a$.