# Can we add an uncountable number of positive elements, and can this sum be finite?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Can we add an uncountable number of positive elements, and can this sum be finite?

I always have trouble understanding mathematical operations when dealing with an uncountable number of elements. Any help would be great.

Comment: Somewhat related: Back in Leibniz's time, the concept of an integral was first conceived as a sum of infinitely many infinitesimal quantities. The idea of infinities being countable or uncountable had not yet been invented then, but if it had, an integral would have been described as a sum of _uncountably many_ infinitesimals, one for each possible value of the integration variable. It later turned out that it is difficult to make this intuition rigorous, but I suspect non-standard analysis might have some way to do it.

Comment: You can find several older related posts. For example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/use-of-sum-for-uncountable-indexing-set) (and in the [linked questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/106102)) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70194/does-uncountable-summation-with-a-finite-sum-ever-occur-in-mathematics) (an in the [linked questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/70194))..

Comment: In particular, this post shows that an uncountable sum cannot be finite if all summands are non-zero: [The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use of $\sum $ for uncountable indexing set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/use-of-sum-for-uncountable-indexing-set)

Comment: @Henning Makholm integral is a sum of COUNTABLE number of infinitelimals.

Comment: @Anixx: No -- the sum of countably many infinitesimals would itself be infinitesimal (each partial sum is less than every $\frac1n$, so their limit would also be).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Suppose $\{s_i : i\in\mathcal I\}$ is a family of positive numbers.$^\dagger$  We can define
$$
\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} s_i = \sup\left\{ \sum_{i\in\mathcal I_0} s_i : \mathcal I_0 \subseteq \mathcal I\ \&\ \mathcal I_0 \text{ is finite.} \right\}
$$
(If both positive and negative numbers are involved, then we have to talk about a *limit* rather than about a *supremum*, and then the definition is more complicated and we have questions of conditional convergence and rearrangements.)

Now consider
\begin{align}
& \{i\in\mathcal I : s_i \ge 1\} \\[4pt]
& \{i\in\mathcal I : 1/2 \le s_i < 1 \} \\[4pt]
& \{i\in\mathcal I : 1/3 \le s_i < 1/2 \} \\[4pt]
& \{i\in\mathcal I : 1/4 \le s_i < 1/3 \} \\[4pt]
& \quad \quad \quad \vdots
\end{align}
If one of these sets is infinite, then $\sum_{i\in\mathcal I} s_i=\infty$.  But if all are finite, then $\mathcal I$ is at most countably infinite.

Thus the sum of uncountably many positive numbers is infinite.

I don't know whether by some arguments about rearrangements one could somehow have some sensible definition of a sum of numbers not all having the same sign that could give us a somehow well defined sum of uncountably many numbers and get a finite number.

---

$^\dagger$ In the initial edition of this answer, I said "Let $S$ be a set of positive numbers and then went on to say
$$
\sum S = \left\{ \sum S_0 : S_0\subseteq S\ \&\ S_0\text{ is finite.} \right\}
$$
However, Dustan Levenstein pointed out in comments that "this definition fails to allow for the same number to occur twice in a sum".  Rather than "twice", I'd say "more than once", since a number might even occur an uncountably infinite number of times.

Comment: I don't think such definition would be actually useful for anything because already the conditionally convergent countable sums are pathological and absolutely aren't good generalization of finite addition.

Comment: If all $S\cap [1/a,  1/(a+1)) $ are finite, why can't $\Sum S $ be finite? Say if all but a finite number of such terms are $0$?

Comment: I think I agree with Blajez. Is this really the best possible definition?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Blazej's comment is referring to the case of including negative numbers. Michael Hardy's definition is perfectly sensible for the case of summing up a system of only positive numbers.

Comment: Although, tiny quibble: this definition fails to allow for the same number to occur twice in a sum.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein- could you please answer the question I asked in the comments section? I don't understand that part of the answer

Comment: You misread Michael's statement. He said if *any* of those intersections is *infinite*, then the sum is automatically infinite. If they're all finite, then there are only countably many (positive) elements of $S$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan : Notice that $0$ is not a member of $S\cap[1/a,1/(a+1))$, so speaking of all but finitely many members of that set being $0$ is at best uninformative. No members of that set can be $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy- Sorry I misread your answer. I was interpreting $S\cap I $ as the sum of the elements in said intersection, whilst you were talking about the number of elements. Thanks!

Comment: I've drastrically edited the answer to allow for some terms to occur more than once. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 9):

We have the next proposition

**Proposition 1.** Let $X$ be an at most countable set, and let $f\colon X\to\mathbf R$ be a function. Then the series $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if $$\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|:A\subseteq X,  A\text{ finite}\right\}<\infty.$$

Inspired  by  this  proposition,  we  may  now  define  the  concept  of an  absolutely  convergent  series  even  when  the  set  $X$  could  be uncountable.

**Definition 2.** Let $X$ be a set (which could be uncountable), and let $f\colon X\to\mathbf R$ be a function. We say that the series $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if $$\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|:A\subseteq X,  A\text{ finite}\right\}<\infty.$$

Note  that  we  have  not  yet  said  what  the  series $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$ is equal  to.  This  shall  be  accomplished  by  the  following proposition.

**Proposition 3.** Let  $X$  be  a  set  (which  could  be  uncountable),  and let  $f\colon X\to\mathbf R$ be  a  function  such  that  the  series  $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$  is absolutely  convergent.  Then  the set $\{x\in X:f(x)\ne0\}$  is  at  most countable.

Because  of  this,  we  can  define  the  value  of $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$  for  any absolutely  convergent  series  on  an  uncountable  set  $X$  by  the  formula $$\sum_{x\in X} f(x):=\sum_{x\in X:f(x)\ne0} f(x),$$ since  we  have  replaced  a  sum  on  an  uncountable  set  $X$  by  a  sum on  the  countable  set $\{x\in X:f(x)\ne0\}$.  (Note  that  if  the former  sum  is  absolutely  convergent,  then  the  latter  one  is  also.) Note  also  that  this  definition  is  consistent  with  the  definitions  for  series  on  countable  sets.

**Remark.** The definition of series on countable sets that are use is

**Definition 4.** Let  $X$  be  a  countable set,  and  let  $f\colon X\to\mathbf R$  be  a  function.  We  say  that  the  series $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$  is  *absolutely  convergent*  iff  for  some  bijection  $g\colon\mathbf N\to X$,  the  sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f(g(n))$  is  absolutely  convergent.  We  then  define the  sum  of $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ by  the  formula $$\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f(g(n)).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be a positive unlimited integer of nonstandard analysis. Then, for example, the sum

$$ \sum_{n=1}^H n = \frac{H(H+1)}{2}$$

is a sum of uncountably many positive numbers... but it's a hyperfinite nonstandard sum, so it exists by the usual methods of nonstandard analysis. The sum is unlimited, though. Other sums can be finite: e.g.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^H \frac{1}{n!}$$

is a finite nonstandard real number that is infinitesimally close to $e$.

That said, IMO, thinking of hyperfinite sums from nonstandard analysis as being sums of uncountably many elements isn't a particularly fruitful line of thought. (also, the sum only works for *internal* sequences of elements anyways; you can't take an arbitrary uncountable collection)

---

I bring this up mainly to show that uncountable sums *can* make sense in some contexts, even if you can't really do much in a standard setting. Each summation operator one might define can have its own sorts of pecularities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more general definition of the sum of any function $f:I\rightarrow E$, where $I=$any non empty set and $E$ is a real or complex topological vector space.

**Definition 1** We say that the family $f=(f(i))_{i\in I}$ is summable in $E$ of sum $\omega\in E$ if and only if, for all neighborhood $V$ of $\omega$, there exists a finite subset $A\subset I$ of $I$ such that for all finite parts $K$ of $I$ containing $A$, we have $\sum_{i\in L}f(i)-\omega\in V$. f is said to be absolutely summable if and only if $\|f\|=(\|f(i)\|)_{i\in I}$ is summable in $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

**Remark 2** This definition does not guarantee the uniqueness of the sum of a given family. The topological vector space $E$ mus be separable for the uniqueness to hold, in which case we write
$$\sum_{i\in I}f(i)=\omega.$$

**Proposition 3** If $E$ is a normed space, then a family $f=(f(i))_{i\in I}$ is summable of sum $\omega$ if and only if for any $0<\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a finite part $A$ of $I$ such that for all finite part $K$ of $I$ with $A\subset K$, we have:
$$\|\sum_{i\in K}f(i)-\omega\|<\varepsilon.$$

**Remark 4** If $f=(f(i))_{i\in I}$ is a family in $E$, we can definie $\mathcal{F}(I)=\{A\subset I:~A~\text{is finite}\}$. Embedding $\mathcal{F}(I)$ with the direction ``$\leq$'' defined by $A\leq B$ in $\mathcal{F}$ iff $A\subset B$, we make $\mathcal{F}(I)$ a directed set (or Riesz space). The if we definite $S:\mathcal{F}(I)\rightarrow E$, by $$S(K)=\sum_{i\in K} f(i),$$ we get a net in $E$. We have the following:

**Proposition 5** $f$ is summable if and only if the set $S(K)$, defined above, is convergent.

Notice that here we have defined the sum of any kind of number, countable or uncountable. But it is proved that in case $E=\mathbb{F}$ and $I=\mathbb{N}$, the summability coincide with the absolute summability, which in turns coincide with the commutative convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(n)$, and the value of the sum of the family is the same as the value of this series.

Comment: This is a very elaborate Answer but it is hard to spot the true conclusion to be drawn:  No, it is not possible for an uncountable set of positive "elements" to have a finite sum.  In particular generalizing to complex numbers seems to obscure the facts; complex numbers are not ordered as positive and not positive.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not possible. Because for an absolutely summable family in a normed sapce $E$, the $\{i\in I: f(i)\neq 0\}$ is at most countable.