# Concerning the definition of zero measure set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

According with the book *Lages Lima - Análise real*, a subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ has zero measure whenever for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable cover made up of open intervals, such that the sum of the lenght of all those intervals is less than $\epsilon$.

My question is : why do we require the cover to be countable?

Comment: In addition to the A from  Zachary Selk: If $X\subset  \cup F$ where $F$ is a family of intervals of $\mathbb R,$  there exists countable $G\subset F$ with $X\subset \cup G.$

Comment: The point is rather that you need to define what is the sum of uncountably many numbers. Whereas the sum of countably many positive number is pretty standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the sum of uncountably many positive numbers is necessarily infinite. See:

[Can we add an uncountable number of positive elements, and can this sum be finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413874/can-we-add-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-elements-and-can-this-sum-be-finit)

Comment: But then it is not necessary to impose the condition of countability since if the cover is made up of uncountably many open intervals then that cover will not satisfy the condition of having a total lenght of less than $\epsilon$, right?

Comment: @laflaca I guess technically you're right but it's just emphasizing the point.