# Showing the Cumulative distribution only has countable plateaus

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function. Show that $F$ only has countably many plateaus.

My idea: Define $A_{n}:=\{[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb R: [a,b]$ is a plateau of length $\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$

I want to prove $|A_{n}|<\infty$, so I assume $|A_{n}|=\infty$

This means there exists $([a_{i},b_{i}])_{i\in \mathbb N}$ so that $\lambda([a_{1},b_{1}])\leq...\leq\lambda([a_{k},b_{k}])$

But I do not know whether I am on the right track here, and how to continue

Comment: The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) CDF has $\infty$ plateaus of length $1$, so you won’t be proving $|A_n| < \infty$. Perhaps you should begin by reviewing the definition of [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413874/can-we-add-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-elements-and-can-this-sum-be-finit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G(q):=\inf\{x\in \mathbb{R}:F(x)\ge q\}$, $0<q<1$ be the corresponding quantile function. A flat region of $F$ corresponds to a jump of $G$. Since $G$ is non-decreasing on $(0,1)$, it can have at most countable number of jumps.

Comment: That last result is because whenever $L_+=\lim_{x \to x_0^+} G(x)$ is different from $L_-=\lim_{x \to x_0^-} G(x)$, there is a rational number in the interval $(L_-,L_+)$ which isn't in the range of $G$. And the monotonicity means this rational number can't be in any of the other "jump intervals" either.

Answer (score 1):

To each plateau you can associate a rational number (namely, some rational number in the interval where your function takes a constant value). These rational numbers are different for each plateau. Therefore, there is an injective mapping from the set of plateaus into the rational numbers. As a consequence, the number of plateaus is at most countable.

Actually, this property does not have anything to do with the non-decreasing nature of the cdf.

Comment: Yes it does, because you used the monotonicity to ensure that the rational numbers are different for all the plateaus. It takes a different argument to show that $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be decomposed into an uncountable union of disjoint intervals.

Comment: The rational numbers I am choosing are not the values of $F$, but some rational number on the intervals where $f$ takes a constant value. It is obviously true that you cannot represent $\mathbb{R}$ as an uncountable union of intervals because all intervals contain a rational number so you cannot have more intervals than rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, I was stuck in the idea for the case of countably many jumps, where the monotonicity is needed in order to ensure that the relevant rational numbers are distinct.