# Hilbert space sum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ as orthonormal set in Hilbert space,

Now define $x = \sum_{i\in I}a_ix_i$ , can we prove $a_i = (x,x_i)$? If $I$ is uncountable set?

I know if we further impose $\sum_{i\in I}|a_i|^2 <\infty$ then set of $i$ such that $a_i \ne 0$ is almost countable（then taking limit,due to continuous of inner product）,what about the case without this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "$x = \sum_{i \in I} a_i \, x_i$". I would say that for any reasonable definition, this series converges if and only if $\sum_{i \in I} |a_i|^2 < \infty$.

Comment: How to show the only if part?

Comment: What is your definition of $\sum_{i \in I} a_i \, x_i$?

Comment: Thank you I find one here  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1413886/360262

Comment: For the countable case, it is easy and follows from $\| \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \, x_i\|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n |a_i|^2$ (due to orthonormality). In the uncountable case, it should work along the same lines.

Comment: Hi I still don't know how to define uncountable sum .