# Positive Sums: Product

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

*Lemma for: [Trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1478762/79762)*

**Positive Sum**

Given the TAS $\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+$.

> For product sums:
>   $$\omega:I\times J\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+:\quad{\sum}_{I\times J}\omega={\sum}_J{\sum}_I\omega$$
>   *(Possibly infinite!)*

How can I prove this?

**Arbitrary Sum**

Given a TAS $\Omega$.

Partial Sums:
$$\omega:I\to\Omega:\quad{\sum}_\Lambda\omega:={\sum}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\omega$$

Index Set:
$$\mathcal{I}:=\{\Lambda\subseteq I:\#\Lambda<\infty\}$$

Index Order:
$$\Lambda\leq\Lambda':\Leftrightarrow\Lambda\subseteq\Lambda'$$

Arbitrary Sum:
$$\sum\omega:={\sum}_I\omega:=\lim_{L\to I}\sum_L\omega$$
*(Convergence!)*

**Remark**

The result extends to TAS!
The proof becomes harder!

*TAS: Topological Abelian Semigroup*

Comment: You definition of $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\varphi_\lambda$ seems a bit unclear to me. Are you missing $\sup$ one RHS? Or do you want to define the sum as limit of the net on the RHS. (This is approach which is often used.) You should also say what are you summing. (Are $\phi_\alpha$'s real numbers. Or are they elements of some topological vector space?) One more minor correction: In the question about double sums one of the sums on the LHS should use $\kappa\in K$ instead of $\lambda\in\Lambda$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: As considering sums, yep they are elements of a TVS. But I really didn't wanted to specify this for the sake of future readers who might be scared away if starting with TVS's. And yes it is meant as a net though being written in a lazy way. ;)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing some parts of your posts. There were some places which seemed to be obvious typos. And also the definition of the sum was not stated very clearly. Since this was the first edit after the closure, this should put the post into reopen review queue. I am not sure whether this will be sufficient to get the post reopened (it was closed as unclear what you are asking). But at least something has to be done, if we want to get it reopened. (If you have something to further improve the post, you should edit it - to increase the chances to get it reopened.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it.. :)*

Existence:
$$\lim_\Lambda\sum_\Lambda\omega=\sup_\Lambda\sum_\Lambda\omega\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+$$

Subnet:
$$\mathcal{W}\supseteq\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}:\quad\overline{\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{W})}\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T})}$$

Continuity:
$$\mathcal{N}(a_++a_+)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{N}(a_+)\oplus\mathcal{N}(a_-)}$$

Supremum:
$$A=\bigcup\mathcal{A}:\quad\sup A=\sup\sup\mathcal{A}$$

By all the above:
$$\lim_W\sum_W\omega=\lim_{S\times T}\sum_{S\times T}\omega
=\sup_{S\times T}\sum_{S\times T}\omega\\
=\sup_T\sup_S\sum_S\sum_T\omega=\sup_T\lim_S\sum_S\sum_T\omega\\
=\sup_T\sum_T\lim_S\sum_S\omega=\lim_T\sum_T\lim_S\sum_S\omega$$
Proving assertion!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear from your post whether you are interested in the case where summands are non-negative real numbers or you want the more general case where summands belong to some topological vectors space.

**Real numbers**

In the case of non-negative real numbers we have $$\sum\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda} c_\lambda = \sup \{\sum\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0} c_\lambda; \Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda; \Lambda_0\text{ is finite}\}.$$

In this case it is pretty straightforward to see that 
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} \sum_{\kappa \in K} a_{\lambda,\kappa} = \sup \{\sum\limits_{(\lambda,\kappa)\in\Lambda_0} a_{\lambda,\kappa}; \Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda\times K; \Lambda_0\text{ is finite}\} = \sum_{\kappa \in K} \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_{\lambda,\kappa}$$

For the addition we have for each $\Lambda_0\subseteq\Lambda$
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0} (a_\lambda+b_\lambda) = \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0} a_\lambda + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0} b_\lambda \le \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_\lambda + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} b_\lambda  $$ 
which implies
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} (a_\lambda+b_\lambda) \le \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_\lambda + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} b_\lambda.$$

To get the opposite direction we notice that for $\Lambda_0=\Lambda_1\cup\Lambda_2$ we get
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1} a_\lambda + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2} b_\lambda \le \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0} (a_\lambda+b_\lambda) \le \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} (a_\lambda+b_\lambda)$$ 
which implies
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_\lambda + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} b_\lambda \le \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda_0} (a_\lambda+b_\lambda) \le \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} (a_\lambda+b_\lambda).$$

**Topological vector space**

If you want to show additivity for more general sums in topological vector space $X$, you can use the fact that $+$ is a continuous map from $X\times X$ to $X$ and that continuous maps preserve convergence of nets.

This result can be also found as [Theorem 9.1.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=VQHqBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114) in Dixmier's General topology.

The second result is not true in arbitrary topological vector spaces. Just consider $\Lambda=K=\mathbb N$ and $a_{n,n}=1$, $a_{n+1,n}=-1$ and other terms zero.
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
  0 &-1 & 1 & 0 & \dots \\
  0 & 0 &-1 & 1 & \dots \\
  \vdots &  &  & \ddots & \ddots 
\end{array}
$$

All vertical sums are zeroes, but one of the horizontal sums is equal to one.

However, it is true at least in Banach spaces if we add the assumption that  the sum $\sum\limits_{(\kappa,\lambda)\in K\times\Lambda} a_{\kappa,\lambda}$ exists.

I found in Dixmier's General Topology [Theorem 9.2.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=VQHqBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114) which says this:

> **Theorem 9.2.2** (Associativity)
>   Let $E$ be a Banach space, $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ a summable family in $E$, $(I_l)_{l\in L}$ a partition of $I$. For every $l\in L$, set $y_i=\sum_{i\in I}$, which is meaningful by 9.2.1. Then the family $(y_l)_{l\in L}$ is summable and $\sum_{i\in I}x_i=\sum_{l\in L} y_l$.

The Theorem 9.2.1 mentioned there says that if some family in a Banach space is summable, then a subfamily is summable, too.

The completeness is used in the proof. (I do not know whether this can be proved for arbitrary normed space, i.e., whether we can omit this assumption.)

The equality you are asking about is a special case of this, since you are asking basically about two partitions of $K\times \Lambda$. But notice that one of the assumption of this theorem is that the sum $\sum\limits_{(\kappa,\lambda)\in K\times\Lambda} a_{\kappa,\lambda}$ exists. Under this assumption it says that either of the two sums will give the same result.

---

I will add that the definition of $\sum\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_\lambda$ using nets is given, for example, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70199). The definition using supremum of finite sums (which is equivalent in the case of non-negative reals) is mentioned in several answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/use-of-sum-for-uncountable-indexing-set).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!! Also I'm pretty fine with the edit of the question - it's a good compromise between keeping the post clean as well as inviting. Like it! :)

Comment: First assertion: In general, consecutive convergence does not imply joined convergence. That works only for monotone(?) sums and so the supremum may handle this. But I myself couldn't work out a nice argument yet. So maybe you'll find a nice way to deal with it.

Comment: You mean an example such that $\sum_{\kappa k\in K} \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_{\kappa,\lambda}$ exists but $\sum\limits_{(\kappa,\lambda)\in K\times\Lambda} a_{\kappa,\lambda}$ does not exist? I think that example with $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ given above is such example.

Comment: Yep, I know, it's the standard example. ;)

Comment: The point why I created this thread is that convergence of the joined respectively 'added' sum implies them separately due to continuity in a TVS. But the converse fails in general. However, for positive sums the equivalence holds in any case even when they fail to converge. That gives a really powerful tool as one is not tempted to check convergence a priori.This way one may check on a formal level Hilbert Schmidt or trace class. *(All that is comparable to Tonelli vs. Fubini.)*

Comment: The theorem on convergence for subfamilies requires completeness. By the way its proof is pretty straightforward: Cauchy-Family implies Cauchy-Subfamily.

Comment: Still it is not obvious to me why: $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\sum_{\kappa\in K}a_{\kappa\lambda}=\sum_{\kappa\in K,\lambda\in\Lambda}a_{\kappa\lambda}$

Comment: @Freeze_S Because both these sums are equal to the supremum of the same set. (I.e., supremum of sums of finite subsets of $K\times\Lambda$.) This is under the assumption that $a_{\kappa,\lambda}$'s are non-negative reals.