# Are Hilbert-Schmidt operators in non-separable Hilbert spaces compact?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

The definition of Hilbert-Schmidt operator should still be valid even when the Hilbert space is not separable:
If $e_i$ for $i\in I$ is an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space, and

$\mbox{Trace}(T)=\sum_{i\in I}\|Te_{i}\|^{2}<\infty$

Then $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt. Of course if the sum is finite then there can only be countably many non-zero terms in the summation.

However, I am not sure how to show that such operators are compact.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you sum over uncountably many elements? (See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/use-of-sum-for-uncountable-indexing-set) for a discussion)

Comment: @Silvia: it should mean at most countably many terms in the summation are nonzero.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $T$ is $0$ except on a separable subspace allow you to deduce this from the same result on separable spaces? FYI - Wikipedia gives the definition on arbitrary Hilbert spaces, just as you do here.

Answer (score 1):

**Preword**

The Hilbert dimension plays no role at all!

**Problem**

A trace class operator is Hilbert Schmidt. *([Decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1508661/79762))*

A Hilbert Schmidt operator is compact. *([Denseness][2])*

Comment: I will provide a proof of the latter later. In particular it will show how to tackle compactness.

Comment: But your post in the link doesn't show why those operators are compact!