# Trace Class: Decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This is only Q&A.*

**Preview**

Trace class operators decompose.
So proofs reduce to Hilbert-Schmidt!

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$.

> For the trace class:
>   $$\mathcal{B}_\textrm{Tr}(\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{B}_\textrm{HS}(\mathcal{H})^*\mathcal{B}_\textrm{HS}(\mathcal{H})\subsetneq\mathcal{B}_\textrm{HS}(\mathcal{H})$$
>   Reminding classes:*
>   $$\mathcal{B}_\textrm{Tr}(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\operatorname{Tr}|A|<\infty\}$$
>   $$\mathcal{B}_\textrm{HS}(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\|A\|_\textrm{HS}<\infty\}$$
>   How can I check this?

**Hilbert-Schmidt Norm: $\|\cdot\|_\textrm{HS}$*

**Motivation**

Relations on trace class operators are complex.
This series aims to enlighten these by reduction.
Hilbert-Schmidt operators become canonical.
Proofs do not require compact operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inclusion**

Suppose $A\in\mathcal{B}_\textrm{Tr}(\mathcal{H})$.

Polar decomposition:
$$A=J|A|=J|A|^{1/2}\cdot|A|^{1/2}$$

But for square root:
$$\left\||A|^{1/2}\right\|_\textrm{HS}^2=\operatorname{Tr}|A|<\infty$$

Concluding inclusion.

**Converse**

Suppose $A,B\in\mathcal{B}_\textrm{HS}(\mathcal{H})$.

Polar decomposition:
$$B^*A=J|B^*A|\implies|B^*A|=J^*(B^*A)$$

Thus one obtains:
$$\operatorname{Tr}|B^*A|=\langle A,BJ\rangle_\textrm{HS}<\infty$$

Concluding converse.

**Strictness**

Given the Hilbert spae $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Consider the operator:
$$A\delta_n:=\frac{1}{n}\delta_n:_\quad\operatorname{Tr}|A|=\infty\quad\|A\|_\textrm{HS}<\infty$$
Concluding strictness.

Comment: How is the trace defined for non-separable Hilbert spaces?