# Is the sequence space over natural numbers $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis

In my homework for functional analysis, we had $\mathcal{H} = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. But the usual sequence space is defined to be a vector space over complex or real numbers. I'm not sure how $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: It's not even a group.

Comment: This is **the** Hilbert space. (Others are either non-separable or isomorphic to this one.)

Comment: @user334639: there's the finite-dimensional ones :)

Comment: As [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) says, $\ell^p$ are special cases of $L^p$ where the space is $\mathbf N$ and the measure is the counting measure. So, is in fact the notation $\ell^p(\mathbf N)$ is the same as you would use for $L^p$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is the space of the (complex or real) sequences $x = (x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ s.t.
$$\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}|x_n|^2 < \infty.$$
The scalar product is
$$(x,y) = \sum_{n\in\Bbb N}x_n\bar{y_n}.$$

Comment: Just clarifying some notation for myself, I can't really find it explicitly anywhere. Is $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ just the same as $\ell^p$? And in general $\ell^p(K)$ is sequences $(a_i)_{i\in K}$? What can $K$ be in that case, any countable set?

Comment: @Christopher.L, yes, yes and usually yes. In fact $K$ *can* be uncountable, but see the problems in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/use-of-sum-for-uncountable-indexing-set.

Comment: Thank you, I will read it more thoroughly later, but do we still call the objects $(a_j)_{i\in K}$ 'sequences' if $K$ uncountable, or something else to distinguish them from sequences as functions from $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Christopher.L, "sequence" implies usually some *order*.