# Uncountable applications of an operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

To simplify matters, assume we have a commutative group $(X,\cdot,1)$ with uncountable $X$. For commutative groups, applications of elements $x_i\in X$ don’t care about order, and we can simply count the number of times each element of $X$ is applied. This means that if we don’t apply any element in $X$ twice, (e.g. $a\cdot b \cdot c$ but not $a\cdot a\cdot c$), then we can simply associate with each application of elements, a set $Y\subseteq X$ (This is just to simplify the question but not essential)

This means we can represent the $\cdot:X\times X\to X$ operator instead as a function $\square : \mathcal P (X) \to X$.

Normally, this set inputted in $\square$ will be finite or at least countable, because when we do applications of elements of $X$ we list this as a *sequence* of applications.

**But the type signature of $\square$ suggests that we can also input uncountable subsets of $X$. Is there a theory about this?** This would be an uncountable application of an operator.

Comment: This is utter nonsense.  You cannot define $\square$ on infinite sets at all, countable or uncountable.

Comment: An infinite sum in the case of $\mathbb R$ would be an example of a countable input to $\square$, right?

Comment: Also I can imagine that integration can be seen possibly in this context (in some interpretation it is a sum of an uncountable amount of infinitessimals)

Comment: @user56834 With $(X,\cdot 1)=(\Bbb Z,+,0)$, what would the infinite "sum" $1+2+3+4+5+\ldots$ be? If you say it's $\infty$ (or even if you say it's $-\frac1{12}$) it is certainly not $\in X$. There is simply no agreaable-upon extension of the concept of sum to infinite sets unless in the cases of very special circumstances (e.g., all but finitely many summands are $=0$). There's a reason why infinite "sums" are actually called series

Comment: Even in the reals most of them would not be defined.

Comment: I am not asking whether we can for any operator define a meaningful uncountable application of it. I’m asking whether there EXISTS some meaningful context in which we have an uncountable application of an operator. The fact that in most cases an infinite application is not defined doesn’t refute that.

Comment: Well, nothing in your question gave any hint that you were interested in special cases rather than an arbitrary abelian group $X$.  In any case, there is no difficulty generalizing the definition of an infinite sum (in the presence of a topology so you can take limits) to an arbitrary index set.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106102/use-of-sum-for-uncountable-indexing-set